# Jenkins - Error ‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘jenkins-eks-pod’

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, groovy, label, jenkins-groovy

After running a pipeline job in Jenkins that runs in my k8s cluster

I am getting this error -

```
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘jenkins-eks-pod’.
```

What am I missing in my configuration?

Pod Logs in k8s-

```
    2023-02-20 14:37:03.379+0000 [id=1646]  WARNING o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Error in provisioning; agent=KubernetesSlave name: jenkins-eks-agent-h4z6t, template=PodTemplate{id='05395ad55cc56972ee3e4c69c2731189bc03a75c0b51e637dc7f868fa85d07e8', name='jenkins-eks-agent', namespace='default', slaveConnectTimeout=100, label='jenkins-non-prod-eks-global-slave', serviceAccount='default', nodeUsageMode=NORMAL, podRetention='Never', containers=[ContainerTemplate{name='jnlp', image='805787217936.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/aura-jenkins-slave:ecs-global-node_master_57', alwaysPullImage=true, workingDir='/home/jenkins/agent', command='', args='', ttyEnabled=true, resourceRequestCpu='512m', resourceRequestMemory='512Mi', resourceRequestEphemeralStorage='', resourceLimitCpu='512m', resourceLimitMemory='512Mi', resourceLimitEphemeralStorage='', envVars=[KeyValueEnvVar [getValue()=http://jenkins-non-prod.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/, getKey()=JENKINS_URL]], livenessProbe=ContainerLivenessProbe{execArgs='', timeoutSeconds=0, initialDelaySeconds=0, failureThreshold=0, periodSeconds=0, successThreshold=0}}]}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Containers are terminated with exit codes: {jnlp=0}
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.checkTerminatedContainers(KubernetesLauncher.java:275)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.launch(KubernetesLauncher.java:225)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:298)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:48)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2023-02-20 14:37:03.380+0000 [id=1646]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Terminating Kubernetes instance for agent jenkins-eks-agent-h4z6t
2023-02-20 14:37:03.380+0000 [id=1646]  SEVERE  o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Computer for agent is null: jenkins-eks-agent-h4z6t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error might be due to not creating the label ‘jenkins-eks-pod’ on the jenkins server.

To create a label on the jenkins server :

> go to manage jenkins > Manage nodes and Clouds > labels and then enter
> the label name.

Post creating this label try to run the job and check if it works.

Refer to this [Blog by Bibin Wilson](https://devopscube.com/jenkins-build-agents-kubernetes/).

As per the error `No httpclient implementations found on the context classloader`  You need to upgrade jenkins kubernetes plugin to 3802. This error No httpclient implementations found on the context classloader is fixed in this release. Refer to this [jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/releases/tag/3802](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/releases/tag/3802.vb_b_600831fcb_3).

Comment: I can't find any labels settings besides the screen shot I've posted.

I tried checking the kubernetes connection (I'm running the jenkins at the same cluster) and got this error -

"Error testing connection https://kubernetes.default: No httpclient implementations found on the context classloader, please ensure your classpath includes an implementation jar"

Comment: ensure that you have the correct version of the Kubernetes client libraries installed on your Jenkins server.

Comment: What version should I have? And what about the fact that I did Test Connection and I got an error.. maybe its related?

Comment: You need to upgrade jenkins kubernetes plugin to 3802. This error `No httpclient implementations found on the context classloader` is fixed in this release. Refer to this [jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/releases/tag/3802](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/releases/tag/3802.vb_b_600831fcb_3). Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Updating fixed this error, and now pods are starting.. but failing really fast..

I've updated the original answer with the logs

Comment: It keep saying offline agent XXXX

Comment: Raise a new question as per stack guidelines and upvote or accept my current solution.

Comment: Done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518522/jenkins-xxxx-is-offline-using-kubernetes-plugin