# Jenkins - 'XXXX' is offline using Kubernetes Plugin

Tags: java, kubernetes, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins as a code and using Kubernetes plugin.
After running a job the job hangs with
'XXXX' is offline.

`Still waiting to schedule task`

`jenkins-eks-agent-37rtx is offline`

```
node ("jenkins-eks-agent") {
echo "hello"
println "hello hello"
```

}

UPDATE -
When I use this config it WORKS! but it seems that it doesn't use my image or any containers I use in my settings or my code, it only use the template I write in the job.....

```
podTemplate(name: 'eks-jenkins-slave') 
    node(POD_LABEL) {
        stage('Run shell') {
                println "hi"
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has any idea what could cause it? I have the most updated kubernetes plugin. I've tried changing to 'WebSocket' connection and change the port to Random for the agent instead of 50000.

Master Jenkins Logs -

```
2023-02-21 09:18:13.619+0000 [id=4049]  WARNING hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter#doFilter: Found invalid crumb 297d7ff4cb091172b92679b0e14a76065f938e102d796d1f217f25dfdeb8450e. If you are calling this URL with a script, please use the API Token instead. More information: https://www.jenkins.io/redirect/crumb-cannot-be-used-for-script
2023-02-21 09:18:13.619+0000 [id=4049]  WARNING hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter#doFilter: No valid crumb was included in request for /job/test/buildHistory/ajax by eilon. Returning 403.
2023-02-21 09:18:18.556+0000 [id=5410]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncAperiodicWork#lambda$doAperiodicRun$0: Started Update IdP Metadata from URL PeriodicWork
2023-02-21 09:18:18.556+0000 [id=5410]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncAperiodicWork#lambda$doAperiodicRun$0: Finished Update IdP Metadata from URL PeriodicWork. 0 ms
2023-02-21 09:18:56.823+0000 [id=5415]  WARNING o.j.p.p.DiskUsageCollector#collect: Cannot collect disk usage data because plugin CloudBees Disk Usage Simple is not installed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudbees/simplediskusage/QuickDiskUsagePlugin
2023-02-21 09:19:49.528+0000 [id=5472]  INFO    hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner#update: jenkins-eks-agent-9mb5k provisioning successfully completed. We have now 2 computer(s)
2023-02-21 09:19:49.631+0000 [id=5473]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Created Pod: kubernetes default/jenkins-eks-agent-9mb5k
2023-02-21 09:20:56.822+0000 [id=5493]  WARNING o.j.p.p.DiskUsageCollector#collect: Cannot collect disk usage data because plugin CloudBees Disk Usage Simple is not installed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudbees/simplediskusage/QuickDiskUsagePlugin
2023-02-21 09:21:29.633+0000 [id=5473]  WARNING o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Error in provisioning; agent=KubernetesSlave name: jenkins-eks-agent-9mb5k, template=PodTemplate{id='05395ad55cc56972ee3e4c69c2731189bc03a75c0b51e637dc7f868fa85d07e8', name='jenkins-eks-agent', namespace='default', slaveConnectTimeout=100, label='jenkins-non-prod-eks-global-slave', serviceAccount='default', nodeUsageMode=NORMAL, podRetention='Never', containers=[ContainerTemplate{name='jnlp', image='805787217936.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/eilon-jenkins-slave:ecs-global-node_master_57', workingDir='/home/jenkins/agent', args='${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}', ttyEnabled=true, resourceRequestCpu='512m', resourceRequestMemory='512Mi', resourceLimitCpu='512m', resourceLimitMemory='512Mi', envVars=[KeyValueEnvVar [getValue()=http://jenkins-non-prod.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/, getKey()=JENKINS_URL]]}]}
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [100000] milliseconds for [Pod] with name:[jenkins-eks-agent-9mb5k] in namespace [default].
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.waitUntilCondition(BaseOperation.java:896)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.waitUntilReady(BaseOperation.java:878)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.waitUntilReady(BaseOperation.java:93)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.launch(KubernetesLauncher.java:171)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:298)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:48)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2023-02-21 09:21:29.633+0000 [id=5473]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Terminating Kubernetes instance for agent jenkins-eks-agent-9mb5k
2023-02-21 09:21:29.704+0000 [id=5473]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#deleteSlavePod: Terminated Kubernetes instance for agent default/jenkins-eks-agent-9mb5k
2023-02-21 09:21:29.704+0000 [id=5473]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Disconnected computer jenkins-eks-agent-9mb5k
2023-02-21 09:21:39.527+0000 [id=5473]  INFO    hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner#update: jenkins-eks-agent-5dwhp provisioning successfully completed. We have now 2 computer(s)
2023-02-21 09:21:39.561+0000 [id=5498]  INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Created Pod: kubernetes default/jenkins-eks-agent-5dwhp
```

Slave Pod Logs -

```
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: jenkins-non-prod-agent.default.svc.cluster.local
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      b1:56:69:f0:b8:34:92:74:44:b0:f9:42:62:cf:c5:29
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins-non-prod-agent.default.svc.cluster.local:50000
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: b1:56:69:f0:b8:34:92:74:44:b0:f9:42:62:cf:c5:29
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader (file:/usr/share/jenkins/slave.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

```
  Agent address: jenkins-non-prod-agent.default.svc.cluster.local
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      b1:56:69:f0:b8:34:92:74:44:b0:f9:42:62:cf:c5:29
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins-non-prod-agent.default.svc.cluster.local:50000
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: b1:56:69:f0:b8:34:92:74:44:b0:f9:42:62:cf:c5:29
Feb 21, 2023 12:48:22 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
```

My agent values -

```
      agent:
        enabled: true
        kubernetesConnectTimeout: 5
        kubernetesReadTimeout: 15
        maxRequestsPerHostStr: "32"
        namespace: default
        image: "805787217936.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/eilon-jenkins-slave"
        tag: "ecs-global-node_master_57"
        workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
        nodeUsageMode: "NORMAL"
        # name of the secret to be used for image pulling
        imagePullSecretName:
        componentName: "eks-global-slave"
        websocket: false
        privileged: false
        runAsUser:
        runAsGroup:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "512m"
            memory: "512Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "512m"
            memory: "512Mi"
        podRetention: "Never"
        volumes: [ ]
        workspaceVolume: { }
        envVars: [ ]
        # - name: PATH
        #   value: /usr/local/bin
        command:
        args: "${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}"
        # Side container name
        sideContainerName: "jnlp"
        # Doesn't allocate pseudo TTY by default
        TTYEnabled: true
        # Max number of spawned agent
        containerCap: 10
        # Pod name
        podName: "jenkins-eks-agent"
        # Allows the Pod to remain active for reuse until the configured number of
        # minutes has passed since the last step was executed on it.
        idleMinutes: 0
        # Timeout in seconds for an agent to be online
        connectTimeout: 100
      serviceAccount:
        annotations: {}
      controller:
        additionalExistingSecrets: []
        JCasC:
          securityRealm: |
            local:
                  allowsSignup: false
                  users:
                    - id: "eilon"
                      password: "Aa123456"
#          securityRealm: |
#            saml:
#              binding: "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
#              displayNameAttributeName: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
#              groupsAttributeName: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group"
#              idpMetadataConfiguration:
#                period: 0
#                url: "https://ironsrc.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/34349e62-799f-4378-9d2a-03b870cbd965"
#              maximumAuthenticationLifetime: 86400
#              usernameCaseConversion: "none"
#          authorizationStrategy: |-
#            roleBased:
#              forceExistingJobs: true
          configScripts:
            credentials: |
              credentials:
                system:
                  domainCredentials:
                    - credentials:
                        - string:
                            scope: GLOBAL
                            id: slack-token
                            description: "Slack access token"
                            secret: "${jenkins-slack-token-non-prod-value}"
                        - usernamePassword:
                            id: "github-credentials"
                            password: "${jenkins-github-token-non-prod-value}"
                            scope: GLOBAL
                            username: "ai-avengers"
            plugin-config: |
              jenkins:
                disabledAdministrativeMonitors:
                  - "hudson.model.UpdateCenter$CoreUpdateMonitor"
                  - "jenkins.diagnostics.ControllerExecutorsNoAgents"
              security:
                updateSiteWarningsConfiguration:
                  ignoredWarnings:
                    - "core-2_263"
                    - "SECURITY-2617-extended-choice-parameter"
                    - "SECURITY-2170"
                    - "SECURITY-2796"
                    - "SECURITY-2169"
                    - "SECURITY-2332"
                    - "SECURITY-2232"
                    - "SECURITY-1351"
                    - "SECURITY-1350"
                    - "SECURITY-2888"
              unclassified:
                slackNotifier:
                  teamDomain: "superops"
                  baseUrl: "https://superops.slack.com/services/hooks/jenkins-ci/"
                  tokenCredentialId: "slack-token"
                globalLibraries:
                  libraries:
                    - defaultVersion: "master"
                      allowVersionOverride: true
                      name: "eilon-jenkins-library"
                      implicit: true
                      retriever:
                        modernSCM:
                          scm:
                            git:
                              credentialsId: "github-credentials"
                              id: "shared-library-creds"
                              remote: "https://github.com/eilon-eilon/eilon-jenkins-library.git"
                              traits:
                                - "gitBranchDiscovery"
                                - "cleanBeforeCheckoutTrait"
                                - "ignoreOnPushNotificationTrait"
        additionalPlugins:
        - junit:1119.1121.vc43d0fc45561
        - prometheus:2.0.11
        - saml:4.352.vb_722786ea_79d
        - role-strategy:546.ve16648865996
        - blueocean-web:1.25.5
        - github-branch-source:1677.v731f745ea_0cf
        - git-changelog:3.23
        - scriptler:3.5
        - sshd:3.249.v2dc2ea_416e33
        - rich-text-publisher-plugin:1.4
        - matrix-project:785.v06b_7f47b_c631
        - build-failure-analyzer:2.3.0
        - testng-plugin:555.va0d5f66521e3
        - allure-jenkins-plugin:2.30.2
        - timestamper:1.18
        - ws-cleanup:0.42
        - build-timeout:1.21
        - slack:616.v03b_1e98d13dd
        - email-ext:2.91
        - docker-commons:1.19
        - docker-workflow:521.v1a_a_dd2073b_2e
        - rundeck:3.6.11
        - parameter-separator:1.3
        - extended-choice-parameter:346.vd87693c5a_86c
        - uno-choice:2.6.3
        adminPassword: ""
        ingress:
          enabled: true
          hostName: jenkins.non-prod.us-west-2.int.isappcloud.com
          ingressClassName: nginx-int
        installPlugins:
        - kubernetes:3883.v4d70a_a_a_df034
        - workflow-aggregator:590.v6a_d052e5a_a_b_5
        - git:5.0.0
        - configuration-as-code:1569.vb_72405b_80249
        jenkinsUrlProtocol: https
        prometheus:
          enabled: true
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "4"
            memory: 8Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 4Gi
        sidecars:
          configAutoReload:
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: 128m
                memory: 256Mi
        statefulSetAnnotations:
          pulumi.com/patchForce: "true"
          Name: eks-non-prod-us-west-2-jenkins
          department: eilon
          division: enterprise
          environment: non-prod
          owner: devops
          project: eks-non-prod-us-west-2-jenkins
          team: infra
        tag: 2.362-jdk11
    version: 4.1.13
```

Comment: can you share the commands you used for raising jenkins and its full (relevant) `values.yaml`

Comment: `changing to 'WebSocket' connection and change the port to Random for the agent instead of 50000.` this is not needed by default

Comment: you see a working example of Jenkins on Kubernetes at my blog where I wrote about how to [Install Jenkins helm chart](https://rokpoto.com/jenkins-docker-in-docker-agent/#install-jenkins-helm-chart)

Comment: I've reverted the websocket and used fixed port of 50000.
Now I've used POD_LABEL and podTemplate inside the job and it works!!!
But how can I use my podTemplate settings without inserting inside each job? it seems like it ignores my settings

Comment: you need to specify agents along with `customJenkinsLabels` in `additionalAgents: ` in charts `values.yaml` . Reference those labels inside the jobs.